# Java queue stop to process emails

Tags: java, email, smtp

I have programme as below which keep receiving email message to be send out. It have been functioning well without any error. Suddenly I notice not sending email without any errors generated. Below is snippet of the codes. In my main I already initialize it  `new Thread(new MailProcessor()).start();`, outside I have put this private `LinkedBlockingQueue<String> eMailQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>();`
and  from another class I call it like this  `eMailQueue.add(sendEmailMessage);` . I restarted it is back to normal operation working well and I would like to know why it stopped for that few hours?

```
  class MailProcessor implements Runnable {
     public void run() {

      Properties props = new Properties();      
      props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");        
      props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");     
      props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");      
      props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");      
      props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");       
      Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,new javax.mail.Authenticator() 
      {             
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() 
        {                   
        return new PasswordAuthentication("*****","******");                
        }       
      });         
       try
       {
         while (true) {

                   try 
                   {
                    int count=0;
                    String emailMessageString = "";
                    emailMessageString = eMailQueue.take();
                    if (emailMessageString.equals(null)) {
                       System.out.println("Email Processor is shutting down");
                    break; // exit while loop, ends run() method
                    }
                       try 
                       {
                            String[] eMArray = null;
                            eMArray = emailMessageString.split("@EmL@");

                            Message emailMessage = new MimeMessage(session);            
                            emailMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress("scvmgr@gmail.com"));
                            emailMessage.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,InternetAddress.parse(eMArray[1]));
                            //System.out.println("EArray Length is :"+eMArray.length+"  "+"Second Email :"+eMArray[2]);
                            if(eMArray.length==3)
                            {
                             String cc1 = eMArray[2];
                             emailMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC,new InternetAddress(cc1));
                            }
                            //emailMessage.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC,InternetAddress.parse(eMArray[2]));
                            //emailMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC,new InternetAddress(cc1));
                            String cc2 = "******";
                            emailMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC,new InternetAddress(cc2));
                            System.out.println("\n\nAlready in add receiptntTypeCC : "+emailMessageString);

                            emailMessage.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.BCC,InternetAddress.parse("shaimyhtc@gmail.com"));
                            emailMessage.setSubject("******");
                            emailMessage.setText(eMArray[0]);
                            //eMailQueue.add(emailMessage);  
                            Transport.send(emailMessage);
                            System.out.println("\n\nSend email :"+eMArray[0]);

                       }
                       catch (Exception e) 
                       {
                       System.out.println("Transport Problem");
                       e.printStackTrace();
                       } 
                   }
                   //System.out.println("Processing " + message);
                   //catch (IOException ex)  
                   catch (Exception e) 
                   {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                   }     

         }
        }
        catch(Throwable th)
        {
          th.printStackTrace();
        }

      }

   }
```

Comment: Could you share the STDOUT or log ? Code appears fine.

Comment: hi vijay i feel it just freeze could it be due to huge traffic. The problem is that in log  I could only see is sending to the MailProcessor thereafter none of the system.out.println of the mail processor is printed. The problem is my log is too big how to post here? Maybe I could email you.

Answer (score 0):

Put a (catch Throwable) outside your while loop and log that. If that occurs, exit and restart the program.

Comment: dear bill, I have edited my codes can you check if that is what your meant? Now how to restart is where I am stuck?

Comment: That will do it. I think what might be occurring is that an error is thrown, which catch Exception will not catch. After that the thread simply terminates (so its not stuck, but dead). catch Throwable and then logging the problem will help you find what is causing the problem. I don't know how you're starting the program so I can't say how best to effect a restart.

Comment: dear bill, this is how I start       new Thread(new MailProcessor()).start();. So are you suggesting to call this line in the catch throwable is it?

Comment: I have not made a specific suggestion about how to do a restart, because I don't know enough about your program. However, as a first step, I would put in the code that catches throwable, logs the problem (as you have already done), and let it run. If the mail thread dies and you get a stack trace then go fix the problem. If the mail thread gets 'stuck' and you have no stack trace then you know there is something else wrong.

Comment: ok bill well will go with your suggestion then try to capture any errors if there is. But about the start that is how I start in the main function during the intialisation process. I would like to ask you something extra what is the difference between try catch and try throwable. What best to use them?

Comment: I think you should post that as another question to help others.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you replace your sysouts with a logging framework(have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85605/can-anyone-recommend-a-simple-java-logging-framework)). It will be much better to find out what happened by examining the log file.

Comment: hi manish,I am running my programe via a java service wrapper. so all my system.out.println are also printed in the wrapper log file. So do you still recommend to switch to other log mechanism?